# I removed Launchpad from dock by mistake, what's the fastest way to bring it back?

Tags: macos, mac, launchpad

I'm new to OSX, so while clearing out multitude of icons that my Macbook Pro came with, I mistakingly removed Launchpad from the dock! After watching a few tutorials, I realize I actually need it for a lot of things. What's the fastest/easiest way to bring it back to the dock?

Essentially what I'm asking is, where do the apps go when you remove them from the dock?

Comment: Create a folder and put things in there you think you don’t want… Also perhaps you should make sure you are using a “user” account that does not have admin level access, you can always put that password in for admin but it **may** just stop you deleting something you shouldn’t.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Ask Different.

Launchpad is an application itself. Apps don't go anywhere when you remove them from the Dock; the Dock is just shortcuts in graphics.

Open the Finder by pressing <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space Bar ␣</kbd>. After the Finder is launched, go to the Applications folder within Finder by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd>. Find the Launchpad application in the Applications folder and hold and drag it down with your mouse to the position where you want it in the Dock. See this article called "[How to Add Launchpad to the Dock on a Mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/678014/how-to-add-launchpad-to-the-dock-on-a-mac/)" for more details.

If you wish to start the Launchpad without using its icon in the dock even after you place it back, you can do that by pressing the Launchpad key (F4) on your keyboard.